# Is there a semantic difference between -icus and -alis?

Tags: suffixes, word-formation

As far as I know both suffixes can be used to create an adjective from a noun.

e.g. [numericus](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:%C5%92uvres_de_Blaise_Pascal,_III.djvu/615) and [numeralis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/numeralis) (and even [numericalis](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricitas)!)

Is there a semantic difference between them, a preferred suffix for words of a certain declension, etc.?

Comment: Wiktionary is a good, yet not always reliable source. Check it.